# What can to do operation in background in android?

Tags: android, background

I have a question for all.

I have an application on android that verifies every 30 seconds if there is a connection with Internet. If there is memorized information in database saved on smartphone, this information must be communicated with the server.

For this solution I have used "Service", but I'm not sure that it is the better solution.

Does Somebody have different idea?

Comment: you can use a `Asyntask` thread, in my opinion it's better solution, you will use less CPU and you have better Memory Leak, read about it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thanks a lot, this work also the application is closed?

Comment: yes, works when app its closed, for example you can put that app on startup device and always your asyntask will be "running"

Comment: But with class "TimerTask" I to attend the 30 seconds, it is correct?

Comment: Yes, you could implement `TimerTask` too.

Comment: I have fixed the English

Answer (score 0):

Since your app doesn't have to run continuously, have a look on the next topics:

1) [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for waking up the phone every 30 sec. Otherwise you will drain your battery.

2) [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which will be start after every alarm fired (you need `START_NOT_STICKY`) and check if there is connection.

3) [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for database.